# Get child node attribute value based on parent node attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a xml given below

```
 <session xmlns="http://test.net/schema/session/1.0" name="test" start="2015-07-01T07:20:31.425Z">

  <download>
    <filename value="/UAT/Incoming/ Status/Archive/8-22-2011 3-20-14 PM306.xml" />
    <result success="false">
      <message>Timeout waiting .</message>
    </result>
  </download>
</session>
```

I want to select the `message` node value only if `Result` node value is false.
I donot want to check on hard coded parent node like node download because it may change

Can anyone help me please..

Comment: Xpath is your friend: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://test.net/schema/session/1.0");

IEnumerable<XElement> failures =
    doc
        .Descendants(ns + "download")
        .Concat(doc.Descendants(ns + "upload"))
        .Elements(ns + "result")
        .Elements(ns + "message")
        .Where(e => e.Parent.Attributes("success").Any(a => !(bool)a));
```

From your input I got this:

[image: result]

Comment: This is fine. But if the parent node is not contstant .. I mean instaead of <download> there may be node like <upload>.Then what will be the solution

Comment: @sandeep.mishra - I've added an upload solution. Will there be more than those two?

Answer (score 3):

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("your xml file path");
        var result = doc.Elements().
            First(e => e.Name == "download")
        .Elements().First(e => e.Name == "result");
        if (result.Attributes().First(a => a.Name == "success").Value == "false")
            return result.Elements().First(e => e.Name == "message").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think an explanation of what your code does might be helpful!

Comment: This is fine. But if the parent node is not contstant .. I mean instaead of <download> there may be node like <upload>.Then what will be the solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set the namespace for your XML file like this:-

```
XNamespace ns = "http://test.net/schema/session/1.0";
```

I will start looking into descendants of `download` because I need to find the `result` element which contains the `success` attribute (whose value we want to check). Thus, a simple where condition will filter those nodes for us and finally we can select the `message` node.

**Update:**

You can use `Concat` if you want to search both download & upload like this:-

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "download")
                                 .Concat(xdoc.Descendants(ns + "upload"))
              .Where(x => x.Element(ns + "result") != null && 
                  (string)x.Element(ns + "result").Attribute("success") == "false")
              .Select(x => x.Element(ns +"result").Element(ns +"message"));
```

I am also checking in the where clause if result node exist or not by checking for null, otherwise it may result in Null reference exception.

Comment: The node download may vary it may be upload . Can you please suggest ageneric way?

Comment: @sandeep.mishra - If I have understood you correctly, you need a `Concat` and then you can have both upload & download. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Using some XPath, the following piece of code should work

```
    string xml = @"<session xmlns=""http://test.net/schema/session/1.0"" name=""test"" start=""2015-07-01T07:20:31.425Z"">    
      <download>
        <filename value=""/UAT/Incoming/ Status/Archive/8-22-2011 3-20-14 PM306.xml"" />
        <result success=""false"">
          <message>Timeout waiting .</message>
        </result>
      </download>
    </session>";

    XmlDocument xdoc  = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

    // Here, you load the namespace used in your xml. You'll need it later in your XPath queries
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("test", "http://test.net/schema/session/1.0");

    // XPath to select the "result" node whose attribute "success" equals false
    XmlElement xelt = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("descendant::test:download/test:result[@success=\"false\"]", nsmgr) as XmlElement;

    // return the "message" node
    return xelt.FirstChild as XmlElement;
```

As already mentioned, you'll find more details about XPath expression on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx